# JsonArrayRequest not working in Android Studio: Can not resolve constructor

Tags: java, android, json

I'm quite new to Java/Android Studio and am spending the past two days figuring this out, without succes. I keep getting: Cannot resolve constructor 'JsonArrayRequest(int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener)'

On other threads I see answers that suggest to replace the null to a string or cast the null but this doesn't seem to make the trick.

I'm trying to read the JSON Array at https://www.smartvibes.be/profiles/api/profileview.php?id=5073 for instance.

This is my code:

```
package com.smartvibes.smartbeat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class profileViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue rs;
    String url,id, nick, age, city, mainpic, numpics, extrapic0, extrapic1, extrapic2, extrapic3, extrapic4, extrapic5;
    TextView profileIntro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_view);
        Bundle getProfileId = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(getProfileId == null){
            return;
        }
        String profileid = getProfileId.getString("profileid");
        url = "https://www.smartvibes.be/profiles/api/profileview.php?id="+profileid;
        rs = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        sendjsonrequest();
        profileIntro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profileIntro);
        //profileIntro.setText(profileData.getPnick());
        profileIntro.setText(profileid);
    }

    public void sendjsonrequest(){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {

                // Get current json Array
                JSONArray profile = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jresponse = profile.getJSONObject(0);
                        Toast.makeText(profileViewActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        nick = jresponse.getString("nick");
                        age = jresponse.getString("age");
                        city = jresponse.getString("city");
                        mainpic = jresponse.getString("mainpic");
                        numpics = jresponse.getString("numpics");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });
        rs.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

When trying to run it I get:

```
error: no suitable constructor found for JsonArrayRequest(int,String,String,<anonymous Listener<JSONArray>>)
constructor JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(String,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor JsonArrayRequest.JsonArrayRequest(int,String,JSONArray,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

I'm probably doing something (or several things) bad... But can't figure out what.

Comment: changing "" to null gives the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss `Response.ErrorListener()`

Use this

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {

                 // Get current json Array
                 JSONArray profile = new JSONArray(response);
                          JSONObject jresponse = profile.getJSONObject(0);
                          Toast.makeText(profileViewActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          nick = jresponse.getString("nick");
                          age = jresponse.getString("age");
                          city = jresponse.getString("city");
                          mainpic = jresponse.getString("mainpic");
                          numpics = jresponse.getString("numpics");

                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            // Do something when error occurred
                            Snackbar.make(
                                    mCLayout,
                                    "Error...",
                                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show();
                        }
                    }
            );
```

Hope it's help

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems fine in your codes except `ErrorListener`.

If you check the source of the [**`JsonArrayRequest`**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/kitkat-cts-dev/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java#39), you'll notice that it takes another method as the last parameter which handles the errors which ***you don't have it***.

Simply, adding the `Response.ErrorListener()` right after the `onResponse()` method will solve the issue.

You can however make it `null` to ignore errors, which is *not recommended*.

**Take a look:** https://android--examples.blogspot.com/2017/02/android-volley-json-array-request.html